# Using a variable in a subprocess.Popen command

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Right now I have a test file.dat that I run hexdump on and put the output into a hexdump.dat file.

```
subprocess.Popen(['hexdump file.dat > hexdump.dat' ], shell=True)
```

As a side note, I have seen suggestions to not use `shell=True` but I essentially get the error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

So, I would like to be able to pass in a variable or an array, files, instead of the hardcoded "file.dat". "files" could be a user input or an array/list generated from a previous subprocess section.

I have tried a user input case:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT 
files = raw_input('File Name: ')                                                                                                 
p = subprocess.Popen(['hexdump files > hexdump.dat' ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)                                         
out,err = p.communicate(input=files)
```

Also with:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['hexdump',  inputs, ' > hexdump.dat' ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Thanks for the help, I know I'm not appropriately understanding the structure needed here so some "handholdy" answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue with what you tried ?

Comment: Error Output :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratchpadDecoder.py", line 47, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(['hexdump file.dat > hexdump.dat' ])
  File "/dsw/python-2.7.1/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/dsw/python-2.7.1/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `shell=True` because otherwise it'll look for an executable with that name. `shell=True` tells the method to use the shell to execute the command so `>` and friends become what you originally intended them to be (redirection).

The following code you posted:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT 
files = raw_input('File Name: ')                                                                                                 
p = subprocess.Popen(['hexdump files > hexdump.dat' ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)                                         
out,err = p.communicate(input=files)
```

will not work because you're just passing `files` to `hexdump`, and if a file with the name `files` doesn't exist you'll get an error (and if it does exist, it's still probably not what you wanted.)

What you want is to build the string you're executing:

```
file = "input.dat"
p = subprocess.Popen("hexdump " + file + " > hexdump.dat", shell=True)
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I had thought I had tried the "+" combo in the past with no difference between commas but I guess that was for a different issue. Very pleased.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that while I was answering your question about variables, the code I've posted isn't really idiomatic. The answers that don't use shell=True and use the redirection provided by the subprocess module have better code.

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: Passing `shell=True` can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input. See the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.

Something like:

```
with open('hexdump.dat', 'wb') as f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['hexdump', 'file.dat'], stdout=f)
    p.wait()
```

You should read up on [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and what the `shell` argument does, and make your decision.

Comment: you could use `subprocess.check_call()`  instead of `Popen().wait()` here

Comment: True, I just kept the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting with `>`, you can redirect using the stdout param. As for the list of files, you can just append the list of files to an array containing hexdump, ie

```
myfiles = ['file1','file2']
with open('hexdump.dat', 'w') as output:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['hexdump'] + myfiles, stdout=output)
```

Comment: The only hiccup with this is that I think it puts all the hexdumps into one hexdump.dat and I still need them distinct for later usage. But I will see about incorporating this when I address the array issue.

Comment: what's the array issue? if you want to output multiple files, you'll need to use a loop or something to that effect

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the error : TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: "array issue" as in once I build the back end for that, right now I'm testing this with an array of one test case

Comment: No reason for `communicate()`. There is no data to send or receive.

Comment: make sure it's ['hexdump'] + ['file1'] and not  ['hexdump'] + 'file1'

Answer (score 1):

I found the simplest way for me to do shell redirection with python and variables is as follows:

```
subprocess.check_output('svnadmin load %s < %s' % (repo, fname), shell=True)
```

It can handle very large files.

Answer (score -1):

First off, in regards to file not found, you may need to specify the current working directory.

```
subprocess.Popen(['hexdump file.dat > hexdump.dat' ], shell=True, cwd='/bar/foo')
```

In regards to passing in an array as an argument, that is typically something like:

```
args = [ 'hexdump', ] + inputs
subprocess.Popen( args, cwd='/foo/bar' )
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to have something like:  args  = ['hexdump', ] +inputs + [> hexdump.dat]?